# SwiftUI Button text alignment issue

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I want to make UI in watch app like this

[image]

But the info button text alignment is not proper. see the below image:
Tried with both text "i" and system image 'info', still same issue

[image]

This is my code:

```
        VStack {
            TextField("User Name", text: $userName)
                .textContentType(.username)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .textContentType(.password)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    //action
                }) {
                    Text("Go")
                }.disabled(userName.isEmpty || password.isEmpty)
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 40, alignment: Alignment.bottom)
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        //action
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "info")
                    }.frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: Alignment.bottom)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(Color.white)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't need those frame alignments and spacer, by removing those let default center alignment take effect:

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {   // << here !!
    Button(action: {
        //action
    }) {
        Text("Go")
    }.disabled(userName.isEmpty || password.isEmpty)
        .frame(width: 80, height: 40)

    Spacer()
    
    Button(action: {
        //action
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "info")
    }.frame(width: 25, height: 25)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .background(Color.white)
    .clipShape(Circle())
}
```

Comment: With this code, the info button is center aligned to 'Go' button. But I want info button bottom aligned to 'Go' button!.

Comment: please see updated with added alignment bottom in HStack

Comment: Accepted as answer.. But forgot to say Thanks :). BTW can we move the whole HStack on bottom of the screen. Means VStack with content on top (two text fields) and bottom HStack